# How can I save an arraylist filled with objects of type person using onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable, onsaveinstancestate

I have this list:

```
private ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
```

And this list is filled with random people. Whenever I turn my screen, the list refreshes and a new list appears. I dont want this to happen.

I have tried to do this with the onSaveInstanceState method like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", people);
}
```

but i get the following error at people:

```
Required type: ArrayList <? extends Parcelable>
Provided: ArrayList<Person>
```

I am able to fix this error by changing the code to:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) people);
}
```

But when I go to the onCreate method where I want to data to load I use this code:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        people = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Required type: ArrayList <Person>
Provided: ArrayList<Parcelable>
```

What can I do to make this work? Ive looked everywhere but cannot seem to find the solution.
I just need the list to remain the same whenever the screen rotates.

Comment: Hey, try extending your Person class with Parcelable class. Then, simply do: 
`outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", people);`

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please also have a look at the android documentation. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states and keep your eye open for ViewModels. Hard to explain in one answer or comment, but it's worth giving architecture components a try.

Comment: Since I am only providing links I won't add an answer. But also follow those links (activity states general): https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras and parcelables: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible ways to solve the problem:

- Save the list in `onSaveInstanceState()` by having your class `Person` implement the `Parcelable` interface. See the Android documentation about how to implement `Parcelable` (you will need to implement a few additional methods to save and restore the data in the `Person` instance.
- Use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. You can return your list of `Person` objects in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and then you can retrieve it in `onCreate()` when your `Activity` is recreated (after Android kills it due to the orientation change).
- Declare the variable `static`, in which case it will not be reinitialized after Android kills your `Activity` and creates a new one. This is not the preferred method, but it is the simplest one.